# Start Erlang on startup.

Tags: erlang, configure, autostart

I'm working on using erlang development server. Is there a way fro me to start the erlang vm and continue from the commandline or add a script to the startup files? To be clear I want to start erlang and keep it running outside of the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the -detached flag. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use scripts, which `rebar create-node` do provide. There is such commands as: start, stop, ping and attach. Although you must use erlang [releases](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word) in order to use this scripts (at list take a look at [template](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/blob/master/priv/templates/simplenode.runner#L141), maybe it would be helpful)